# Are these expressions, for the EPV of a benefit paid by an insurance policy, equivalent?

Tags: actuarial-science

The following screenshot shows part of the provided lecture notes for a module on actuarial mathematics:

[image: notes]

My question is as follows: is this equation equivalent to simply writing
$$
\bar{A}_x^{ik} = \int_0^\infty e^{-\delta t} {}_t p_x^{ik} \hspace{1mm} dt
$$

Why bother to add the additional consideration of first moving into an unrelated state $j$ at time $t$, rather than simply considering the transition directly into state $k$ from the initial state $i$?

Either the expression in the lecture notes is unnecessarily convoluted, or my expression is incorrect. If the latter is the case, what makes my expression wrong?

Comment: How about explaining what all these terms mean?  What is EPV, MSM?  BTW, for anyone else trying to decode this, I've figured out that "jnenk" means $j\ne k$

Comment: EPV is standard in actuarial/financial mathematics and stands for expected present value. MSM stands for multiple state model. 'jnek' is indeed supposed to be $j \neq k$ and is just the result of the lazily written resources we were provided.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the notation, your simplification is not correct.  $_tp_x^{ik}$ is the probability that a life aged $x$  in state $i$ at time $0$ is in state $k$ at time $t$.  But the instrument pays at the moment of transition to state $k$.  Your integral would have it paying at all times when the life is in state $k$.